# 'Url' does not contain a definition for 'RouteUrl'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
Good day!
```

I try to learn ASP MVC vNext (6?) , so i use [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6),  but when i type this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void CreateTodoItem([FromBody] TodoItem item)
    {

        item.Id = 1 + _items.Max(x => (int?)x.Id) ?? 0;
        _items.Add(item);

        string url = Url.RouteUrl("GetByIdRoute", new { id = item.Id },
                Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToUriComponent());

        Context.Response.StatusCode = 201;
        Context.Response.Headers["Location"] = url;
    }
```

I have the error message:'Url' does not contain a definition for 'RouteUrl'.

I add this usings, but it does no help:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Server;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Security.Policy;
```

Please, help me to fix this errors!

Answer (score 1):

Url.RouteUrl is in the System.Web.Mvc.dll  so add `using System.Web.Mvc;`

looking back at this Url.RouteUrl is in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace in MVC6.  you seem to have that so I'm not 100% sure.  could be missing reference files or other compile errors.